# Emoji input (only) in Watchkit

Tags: ios, input, watchkit, apple-watch, emoji

I'm currently making a WatchKit app and I'm playing with the user input options.

I'd like to place a couple buttons in the messaging area that go straight to voice and emoji inputs.

I know that I can place just one button with both options enabled with

> presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: nil, allowedInputMode: .allowEmoji, completion:{(message)

but I'd like to place two separated buttons in order to display the voice dictation or emoji in an easier way with just one tap. Apple does this with the messages app currently and I was wondering if it is something that we are also able to do.

[Apple messages buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSmny.png)

Is this something that can be done?

Thank you for the help